# Positive Projections on Matrix Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{M}_d$ be the space of complex valued $d\times d$ matrices, and $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{M}_d$ a subspace. Let $P_{\mathcal{S}}$ be a projection onto $\mathcal{S}$. My questions is about what properties must $\mathcal{S}$ fulfill to guarantee that there exists a $P_{\mathcal{S}}$ with the property of being positive preserving. Example: if $\mathcal{S}={\rm span}(A)$ where $A$ a positive semidefinite matrix, then by using the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product, one constructs a positive preserving $P_{\mathcal{S}}$ (completely positive actually).

Comment: What do you mean by "the" projection onto $\mathbb S$?

Comment: @Martin Argerami, I mean $P_{\mathcal{S}}A=A$, $\forall A\in \mathcal{S}$, and $P_{\mathcal{S}}^2=P_{\mathcal{S}}$.

Comment: @Martin Argerami, Ok, I have edited the question, I see the word "the" can be confusing. What I'm asking is about the existence of at least one positive preserving projection